# I have problem while passing variables to the second file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem passing variables to second php file.

This is my checkboxtestbackend.php and I need to pass from index.php two variables here.
When i try to use global $variable in index.php this do nothing, if I try to make new variables containing the same information as variables in checkboxtestbacked.php result is the same:

```
$checkboxstatus = $_POST['checkboxstatus'];

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "odcinki";


$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Brak polaczenia" . mysqli_connect_error();}





$query = " UPDATE `1`
           SET lastname = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE id = '$postID' ";
           
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("zesrało sie i chuj");
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "odcinki";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Brak polaczenia" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$postID = get_queried_object_id();
   
   $current_user =  wp_get_current_user();
   
   $current= $current_user->ID ;

$sql = "SELECT lastname FROM `$current` WHERE id = '$postID'";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$keepchecked= $row['lastname'];

}







?>

 <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {     ?> Status: <input type="checkbox" name = "seks" value ="1" id="checkboxtest" <?php echo ($keepchecked == "YES") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
    if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
   
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        success: function(result) {
                console.log('the data was successfully sent to the server');
            }
        })
        
});
});
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this

```
$checkboxstatus = $_POST['checkboxstatus'];
$postID = $_POST['postID'];


$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "odcinki";


$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Brak polaczenia" . mysqli_connect_error();}





$query = " UPDATE `1`
           SET lastname = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE id = '$postID' ";
           
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("zesrało sie i chuj");
```

> Y0u need to make javascript variables and post it to checkboxtestbackend.php page

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "odcinki";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Brak polaczenia" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$postID = get_queried_object_id();
   
   $current_user =  wp_get_current_user();
   
   $current= $current_user->ID ;

$sql = "SELECT lastname FROM `$current` WHERE id = '$postID'";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$keepchecked= $row['lastname'];

}







?>

 <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {     ?> Status: <input type="checkbox" name = "seks" value ="1" id="checkboxtest" <?php echo ($keepchecked == "YES") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
   var checkboxstatus = "";
   var postID = "<?php echo $postID;?>";
    if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus, postID : postID},
        success: function(result) {
                console.log('the data was successfully sent to the server');
            }
        })
        
});
});
    ?>
```